# Is it okay to have more than one Product (with image, description and SKU) per page?

Tags: microdata, page, schema.org

In a few pages in a website, similar products are displayed in the same page. Each item has its own description (almost identical) and its own SKU (also almost identical).

How can I use Microdata correctly here?

I have tried, for testing purposes, to add the code for image, description and SKU for all 3 items in one page, and I have tested the page in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

Google read the data and displayed the URL for all 3 images, all 3 descriptions, and all 3 SKUs.

Is this the correct approach, or is this wrong?

Not sure if it makes a difference, but at the moment, this is not an e-commerce site.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Test name 1</span>
<img src="test1.jpg" />
<span itemprop="description">Description test 1</span>
<span itemprop="sku">#001</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Test name 2</span>
<img src="test2.jpg" />
<span itemprop="description">Description test 2</span>
<span itemprop="sku">#002</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Test name 3</span>
<img src="test3.jpg" />
<span itemprop="description">Description test 3</span>
<span itemprop="sku">#003</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks okay to me, is there any reason you think it's incorrect?

Comment: It's unclear whether you're allowed to have more than 1 product per page using microdata. There's now explanation or examples of this on schema.org.

Comment: Yes you are allowed to do that, and yes it is correct. See this page for Google terms for schema use: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies Look for the "Multiple entities on the same page" section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to have [Schema Product Properties](http://schema.org/Product) for multiple products on a page, as demonstrated here:

[Schema.org Markup of a SERP / Product Listing](http://scottgale.com/schema-org-markup-serp/2013/03/17/)

(And in the top example of [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51944/structured-data-google-data-highlighter) related question)

If Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) displays each of the items under the `Extracted structured data` section with the correct data, as it does [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://scottgale.com/blogsamples/serp/index.html&html=) (using the example in the first link above), then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google's [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) does not show any warning for marking up multiple products with microdata on one page, I would say it's okay to do so.

That said, at the time of writing (2022), doing so does not yield any benefit from Google because the approach is not currently supported by the search engine.

This is what Google's [Technical guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/product#technical-guidelines) says about using the Product itemtype:

> **Use markup for a specific product, not a category or list of products.** For example, "shoes in our shop" is not a specific product. Currently, product rich results only support pages that focus on a single product. This includes product variants where [each product variant has a distinct URL](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/ecommerce/designing-a-url-structure-for-ecommerce-sites#how-google-understands-urls-for-product-variants). We recommend focusing on adding markup to product pages instead of pages that list products or a category of products.