# Structured data: Google Data Highlighter?

Tags: google, search-results, structured-data

We're working on adding structured data for a richer snippet on search engine result pages. There are two type of structured data that I can't figure out how they're done. They seem to show up only on Google, so I'm suspecting Google Data Highlighter, but does anyone have any insights?

Here are some examples.

1. Greyed out text list of products shown on that page.

[image]

2. Clickable links of products shown on that page.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the specific code used by Google for the snippet, this appears to be rich snippet markup for Products, as covered here:  [Google Webmaster Tools - Rich snippets - Products](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750).

Product [Offers](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750#offer_properties) includes the following properties (among others):

- price
- currency
- quantity (which the top snippet appears to have)

Note that this text appears in light grey, as visible in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_-rRxKSm2ic#at=20) video at 0:17 (when price is highlighted).

Other properties includes `offerURL` - a URL to the product's webpage, which the second snippet may have used. Alternatively, it could have used the `url` property as described here at [schema.org/Product](http://schema.org/Product)

Note that currently the page for [Data Highlighter for Products](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2774358) is not available, however, it should use the same [schema.org/Product](http://schema.org/Product) schema, as similarly indicated under "Event Tags" in [Data Highlighter - Events](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2774099?hl=en&ref_topic=2774098)

Comment: The first result is clearly a structured data, but the second one is called Site Links and it's done automatically by Google. You can't influence that in any way. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Comment: @AlexDumitru Not sure about that, Sitelinks usually appear indented, as shown here:  [Google Webmaster Tools - Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?topic=8523). Could be just the URL schema property alone since it's part of the snippet itself (see 1 and 2 in the diagram there).

Comment: This is a new kind of sitelinks that usually appear to newer sites or to sites that aren't on the top position. http://searchengineland.com/new-google-sitelinks-with-small-arrows-110672

Comment: @AlexDumitru No small arrow as indicated in that. It's not a big point though since we can't see the markup anyway ;-)

Comment: There are multiple kinds of sitelinks and Google keeps changing things. But I'm really sure those are generated automatically.

Comment: @Alex, yeah the second one (in the pics) seems to have been generated automatically. I'm aware of Sitelink features that you can add via Adwords, but this seems like a new type.. @dan/Alex, the first one doesn't appear to be structured data, which would be visible when you look at the source code of the linked page. I could not find anything tagged for those products in grey.

Comment: @Youn It could be that Google stores the schema produced with the Data Highlighter on their end.