# Schema.org product variations with same url. Problem?

Tags: microdata

When displaying multiple products that are basically the same, let's call them **Product A** with different sizes, **30**, **40** and **50**, I choose to create only one page per product and avoid duplicates, since the size would really be the only difference.

So in this page, I'm displaying the different product codes based on their size, ie: A30, A40 and A50.

On a different page, for example, where **Product B** is listed, I would like to display related products, in this case, **Product A** (only a list with sizes and codes, no pictures).

I can either display **Product A** by itself (which I don't want to, since a Product B30 would fit a product A30, for example), or display Product **A30**, **A40** and **A50**.

Using schema.org, **itemprop="url"**, I would like to link to this product's page.

The question here is, product **A30**, **A40** and **A50** are all listed in the same URL. Would linking these 3 products to the same URL pose a problem?

Comment: Just to clarify things: you want to list different versions of product A on product B's page, and provide `itemprop="url"` for each version of product A there back to the product A page?

Comment: Yes, using "isAccessoryOrSparePartFor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *Product A* is an accessory or spare part for *Product B*, this shouldn't be a problem since you're using the [isAccessoryOrSparePartFor](https://schema.org/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor) property, which is:

> A pointer to another product (or multiple products) for which this
>   product is an accessory or spare part.

It's natural to list accessories on the same page as the corresponding product, and provide a link to another page for more details on them. And as previously covered [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51934/structured-data-is-it-okay-to-have-more-than-one-image-description-and-sku-per/51985#51985), several products can be listed on a single page.

This is akin to having a page for a printer (*Product B*), and then listing various printer cartridges (*Product A*) there as accessories, which point to a cartridges page that contains content like pictures of the cartridges, compatibility, specs, etc...

It's doubtful that a search engine would view this as a form of manipulation or otherwise since you're indicating the accessory/product relationship, and this type of structuring is common.

Comment: Hi Dan, and thank you for your answer. My question is solely about the links. One would think if there's the "isAccessoryOrSparePartFor" property available, listing more than one product per page wouldn't be a problem and so shouldn't linking. Problem is there's no documentation anywhere about it. I just want to make sure as you said that this is not treated as a form manipulation or something that would hurt this website in any way. Is there anything you found that would support your answer?

Comment: No problem. Yes, I was discussing links in regards to multiple ones pointing back to the same product page, from a page where multiple products are listed as accessories. Since you're using the right property, and schema.org [was created](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158?hl=en) by the major search engines, there really isn't any cause for concern since this doesn't fall under any of the [black hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamdexing) techniques that search engines penalize for (i.e., it's natural).

Comment: You're not always going to find documentation for every specific situation, unless there's cause for it :-)

Comment: I tend to agree with you on that one. Thank for the answer. =]

Comment: No problem. Good luck :-)